# Is there a place I can clone android developer docs from?

Tags: android, sdk, documentation

I know that you can download the docs in the android sdk but the whole thing is like 300MBs and I figure if the docs had a repo, and why shouldn't they since android is open source, I could get a shallow clone of the docs and then just pull it once in a while to have it updated. That way I don't have to download 300MBs every time there's some update.

That being said, can I do the same with the whole framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
I don't think this approach will save bandwidth, though, as you'll need to sync all changes.

1. Clone the source repository with [repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html)

   `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`

   `repo sync -j 10`
2. Build the doc (sac stands for source.android.com)

   `make online-sac-docs`

The whole documentation will be generated in `out/target/common/docs/online-sac`.

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I never ran this myself. For the sake of completeness, what is missing?

Comment: The only thing missing is that once you install `repo` (which is just a script) you have to specify projects for it to download. `-j 10` says to download 10 projects simultaneously which is not really what I want. I might be able to download just the framework or even better, just the docs and build that. And since repo is just a script, you can use git to get the latest version only. With all that said, I now know how to contribute to Android code and for that I am grateful to you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. I'm not sure you can download "just the doc" since it's spread across different projects. `repo` is a wrapper around `git` to make it easier to access different git repositories simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Developer docs are released as part of the AOSP, which is released under the [Apache 2.0 License](http://developer.android.com/legal.html). That means the source code is freely available - Github has a mirrored repo [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/7de7e0b0dd61acba813dec3a07d29f1d62026470/docs/html).

However, just because you can, doesn't mean you should. You will probably be better off downloading the documentation from the SDK manager, as that way you won't have to generate the HTML files from the .jd template files in the repository. You can also configure automatic updates via the SDK manager, which is a lot less error-prone than relying on yourself to regenerate the docs every time the SDK changes. Unless your download speeds are awful, I don't see any reason to go down this road.

Comment: Let's say my download speed is aweful and I do want to build the docs. I'd already cloned the docs but I don't see any instructions on how to build it.

Comment: I believe you would just build the whole Android framework, which is why you're probably better off just downloading it via the SDK manager.